# MySql query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here you have a screenshot from my table structure:

[image]

On my site I have two fields for the search, one for the city (`ort`) and one for industry (`branche`).

If I search for: **Frankfurt verschierung**, let's say that in the field for city I have: **Frankfurt** and in the field for industry (`branche`) I have **verschierung** it doesn't return any results, and I have the data in my database, here you have a screen-cap from the data:

[image]

And here you have my sql query:

```
$do = $this->select("*, MATCH(`ort`) AGAINST ('{$plz}') AS score")
           ->where('MATCH(`branche`) AGAINST( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $branche)
           ->order('premium DESC, score');
```

Any solutions?

**Update:**

```
$do = $this->select("*,MATCH(`branche`,`ort`) AGAINST ('".$branche." ".$plz."') AS score")
    ->where('MATCH(`branche`,`ort`) AGAINST( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', $branche.' '.$plz)
    ->order('premium DESC, score');
```

Now if I search for the SAME terms, I get some results, BUT it doesn't display it correctly, here you have a picture from the search results:

[image]

Only the FIRST result is corect what about the others? Why are they there?

Comment: What the hack is this query? Have your tried run a simple sql query in phpmyadmin? Suggested question title: Zend_Db_Select ~help~, it's not optimalization nor optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using:

```
$do = $this->select()
           ->where("`ort` LIKE ?",'%'.mysql_escape_string($plz).'%')
           ->where("`branche` LIKE ?",'%'.mysql_escape_string($branche).'%')
           ->order("premium DESC");
```

Comment: You shoud note, that this doesn't sort your result by relevance... ;)